# Laravel return error 500 after change template

Tags: php, apache, laravel

Here's the problem:

I've just installed Laravel, and the server works just fine if I use php server by

```
php artisan serve
```

But when I change to use `apache2` by v-host

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName lcbq.localhost
    DocumentRoot /Users/Shared/LCBQ/lcbq/public
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    <Directory /Users/Shared/LCBQ/lcbq>
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        DirectoryIndex index.php
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

It works fine at the beginning, but when I changed the template file `welcome.blade.php`, the start page turn to be blank(error 500).

The weirdest part is, if I use `php server`, this won't happened, it's only happed in apache.

AND, if I open two server both, and I changed the template file, the `apache server` won't work at the beginning, but once I opened the page in `php server`, the `apache server` will work again!

That's really confusing, someone help me plz.

Comment: What error message do you get, apart from that 500? What are the logs saying?

Comment: only 500 in webbrowser, 500 in access_log, nothing in error_log

Comment: nothing in storage/laravel.log neither

Answer (score 0):

you need to clear the compiled view files after changing the template or any view code. ( no need to use command `serve`)

```
php artisan view:clear
```